# A differential topology lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the following lemma 
[image]

[image]

(1) How come he talks about degrees here, after all he doesn't assume $X$ to be oriented?
(2) Why is $\bar{v}|\partial X$ homotopic to $g$? (NOTE: we consider them as maps to $S^{m-1}$ isn't it? This is very important)

I have thought about these questions on my own, but I don't want to give my own answers as I want yours to be independent of my mine (my answers are plausible, so they might convince you even if they are actually wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question (1), the first sentence that you quote says "Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be a compact $m$-manifold with boundary". Since $X$ has the same dimension as $\mathbb{R}^m$, $X$ naturally inherits an orientation from $\mathbb{R}^m$: at a point $p \in X$ we have equality of tangent spaces $T_p X = T_p \mathbb{R}^m$, and so we just use the natural orientaton on $\mathbb{R}^m$ itself.

For question (2), $v$ is by assumption an outward pointing vector field along $\partial X$, and $g$ is by definition the unit outward pointing vector field along $\partial X$. These two vector fields therefore take values in the same component of the open half space $T_p X - T_p \partial X$. So you can define a straight line homotopy between $v$ and $g$ which is never zero. You can then divide each vector in this homotopy by its norm to get a homotopy between $\bar v$ and $g$ taking values in $S^{m-1}$.

Comment: I misread the quote slightly, and have rewritten my answer to be a bit clearer.